# Powershell script to create an xml file

Tags: sql, xml, powershell, command

I have a sql command which will create xml tags , on writing a powershell script i need to create a simple xml file which starts with '<'?xml version=1.0 standalone="yes"?>

as of now i have a ps file like

```
$inputFilePath =D:\abc.sql

$outputFilePath=D:\abc.xml

invoke-sqlcmd -inputFile $inputFilePath | Format-Table -hide -Wrap -AutoSize  | Out-File -filePath $outputFilePath
```

This just creates a file with .xml extention. Can anyone help me with it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try and pipe to the `ConvertTo-Xml` cmdlet. Here's how the output looks like for 3 process objects. You can then pipe it out to a file :

```
PS> gps | select name,id -first 3 | ConvertTo-Xml -As String -NoTypeInformation


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Name">AppleMobileDeviceService</Property>
    <Property Name="Id">1568</Property>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Name">audiodg</Property>
    <Property Name="Id">5140</Property>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Name">Babylon</Property>
    <Property Name="Id">4908</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```